# Django python GET http://localhost:8000/topics 404 (Not Found)

Tags: python, django, get

I am learning Django using *"Python Crash Course"* by *Eric Matthes* ch.18- 20. I am trying to run the get request of my topics.html and I'm getting the error below...

**GET http://localhost:8000/topics 404 (Not Found)**

File urls.py /learning_log

```
# from django.conf.urls import include, url OUT_OF_DATE
from django.urls import include, re_path as url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),
]
```

File urls.py /learning_logs

```
"""Defines URL patterns for Learning_logs."""

# from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import re_path as url
from learning_logs import views

app_name = 'learning_log'
    
urlpatterns = [
    # Home Page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    # Show all topics.
    url(r'^$', views.topics, name='topics'),
]
```

File views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from learning_logs.models import Topic

def index(request):
    """The home page for Learning Log."""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):
    """Show all topics."""
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topic': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

Comment: The first argument of `url` is a url path that you enter into address bar. `name` is a name used for resolving in django and JTL code. So now you have two pages on the same location (probably `/` will resolve to `views.topics`, but not sure here). Change the path

Comment: I'm the author of Python Crash Course. The copy you're using is from ~2016, before Django 2.0 came out. URL patterns are much simpler in Django now, and there have been numerous other changes as well. I encourage you not to use the copy you have; if you want to stay with PCC you should pick up a copy of the second edition, which is fully compatible with Django 4.0. Or, pick up a more specific Django resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
url('topics', views.topics, name='topics'),
```

if not worked

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
  path('topics', views.topics, name='topics'),
]
```